# How to modify the following code to express the numeric value into word value according to Indian counting system

Tags: php, algorithm

The following code expresses the numeric value into word value by categorizing the number into different cases and using the default case for finding the baseunit and the number and the remainder and recursively calling the following function to express the number into words. What I want to achieve is to get the value expresed into Indian counting system and not using million, billion etc.

I feel if modify this line in default: `$baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));`
correctly then I will be able to solve the problem.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
function convert_number_to_words($number) {

    $hyphen      = '-';
    $conjunction = ' and ';
    $separator   = ', ';
    $negative    = 'negative ';
    $decimal     = ' point ';
    $dictionary  = array(
        0                   => 'zero',
        1                   => 'one',
        2                   => 'two',
        3                   => 'three',
        4                   => 'four',
        5                   => 'five',
        6                   => 'six',
        7                   => 'seven',
        8                   => 'eight',
        9                   => 'nine',
        10                  => 'ten',
        11                  => 'eleven',
        12                  => 'twelve',
        13                  => 'thirteen',
        14                  => 'fourteen',
        15                  => 'fifteen',
        16                  => 'sixteen',
        17                  => 'seventeen',
        18                  => 'eighteen',
        19                  => 'nineteen',
        20                  => 'twenty',
        30                  => 'thirty',
        40                  => 'fourty',
        50                  => 'fifty',
        60                  => 'sixty',
        70                  => 'seventy',
        80                  => 'eighty',
        90                  => 'ninety',
        100                 => 'hundred',
        1000                => 'thousand',
        //Instead of the following values I would like to have Indian counting system values
        /*
        1000000             => 'million',
        1000000000          => 'billion',
        1000000000000       => 'trillion',
        1000000000000000    => 'quadrillion',
        1000000000000000000 => 'quintillion'
       */
        100000   => 'lakhs',
        10000000 =>'crore',
        1000000000 =>'arab',
        100000000000  =>'kharab' 
    );

    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
        // overflow
        trigger_error(
            'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
            E_USER_WARNING
        );
        return false;
    }

    if ($number < 0) {
        return $negative . convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
    }

    $string = $fraction = null;

    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
    }

    switch (true) {
        case $number < 21:
            $string = $dictionary[$number];
            break;
        case $number < 100:
            $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
            $units  = $number % 10;
            $string = $dictionary[$tens];
            if ($units) {
                $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
            }
            break;
        case $number < 1000:
            $hundreds  = $number / 100;
            $remainder = $number % 100;
            $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $conjunction . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
        default:
            $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
            $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
            $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
            $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                $string .= convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
    }

    if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
        $string .= $decimal;
        $words = array();
        foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
            $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
        }
        $string .= implode(' ', $words);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, instead of `$baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));` you need to have it take on the largest out of lakhs, crore, arab and kharab. A dirty solution would be to see if it's greater than each of those numbers from highest to lowest, and set it to the highest one it is, and then go from there.

Comment: @Patashu, in million, billion and trillion each one is 1000 times bigger then the previous one but in my case it is 100 times bigger so my baseunit should be pow(100, floor(log($number, 100))).

Comment: Incorrect. 100*100 is 10000 but lakhs is 100000, an extra factor of 10

Comment: Yeah that's what keeping me from getting a solution.

Comment: you want: $baseUnit = 10 * pow(100, floor(log($number / 10, 100)));

Comment: Heartiest Thanks goes to patashu also. Both of you are great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For public benefit  I would Like to post the full solution.

The following PHP function provides us with a way to convert from numeric to word format expressed in Indian counting sytem.

Thanks goes to Patashu and rici for helping me finding my way through  :-

```
function convert_number_to_words($number) {
    $hyphen      = '-';
    $conjunction = ' and ';
    $separator   = ', ';
    $negative    = 'negative ';
    $decimal     = ' point ';
    $dictionary  = array(
        0                   => 'zero',
        1                   => 'one',
        2                   => 'two',
        3                   => 'three',
        4                   => 'four',
        5                   => 'five',
        6                   => 'six',
        7                   => 'seven',
        8                   => 'eight',
        9                   => 'nine',
        10                  => 'ten',
        11                  => 'eleven',
        12                  => 'twelve',
        13                  => 'thirteen',
        14                  => 'fourteen',
        15                  => 'fifteen',
        16                  => 'sixteen',
        17                  => 'seventeen',
        18                  => 'eighteen',
        19                  => 'nineteen',
        20                  => 'twenty',
        30                  => 'thirty',
        40                  => 'fourty',
        50                  => 'fifty',
        60                  => 'sixty',
        70                  => 'seventy',
        80                  => 'eighty',
        90                  => 'ninety',
        100                 => 'hundred',
        1000                => 'thousand',
        //Instead of the following values I would like to have Indian counting system values
        /*
        1000000             => 'million',
        1000000000          => 'billion',
        1000000000000       => 'trillion',
        1000000000000000    => 'quadrillion',
        1000000000000000000 => 'quintillion'
       */
        100000   => 'lakhs',
        10000000 =>'crore',
        1000000000 =>'arab',
        100000000000  =>'kharab' 
    );

    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
        // overflow
        trigger_error(
            'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
            E_USER_WARNING
        );
        return false;
    }

    if ($number < 0) {
        return $negative . convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
    }

    $string = $fraction = null;

    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
    }

    switch (true) {
        case $number < 21:
            $string = $dictionary[$number];
            break;
        case $number < 100:
            $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
            $units  = $number % 10;
            $string = $dictionary[$tens];
            if ($units) {
                $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
            }
            break;
        case $number < 1000:
            $hundreds  = $number / 100;
            $remainder = $number % 100;
            $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $conjunction . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
        default:
            $baseUnit = 10 * pow(100, floor(log($number/10, 100)));// Thanks to rici and Patashu
            $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
            $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
            $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                $string .= convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
    }

    if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
        $string .= $decimal;
        $words = array();
        foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
            $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
        }
        $string .= implode(' ', $words);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, never used `arab` & `kharab`. Can you point me a source where it says so?

Comment: I have observed it being used all the time, though may not be popular. Indians don't use their own system. Anyway you can always search for them. Search South Asian Numbering system.